# How to union select with random and limit

Tags: mysql, database, select, random, union

I'm trying to random my training data or machine learning. In my table have column that save just two value "A" and "B". But when I using random query, both of that value that show isn't equal and my code isn't working. How to fix this? I'm really bad on MySQL T.T

I'm using MySQL on XAMPP

```
SELECT * FROM
(
      (SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.category = 'A' LIMIT 10) as t1
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.category = 'A' LIMIT 10) as t2
)ORDER BY RAND()
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as t2
) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 25' at line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't give aliases to the tables in `UNION`, only in `FROM` or `JOIN`. So use

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.category = 'A' LIMIT 10)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.category = 'B' LIMIT 10)
) AS t1
ORDER BY RAND()
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iqaisid2d3MNbv8HCXoGud/0)

Comment: Thank you, but now i still can't show the result that i want..
From your code, the result is only show 10 row on category B but random. But i want show 10 row category A random too. Can you fix this?

Comment: I've added a db-fiddle demo.

Comment: The code in your question has the same category in both subqueries. Make sure you don't make the same typo when you're testing.

Comment: Thank you, it's work hahaha
But i still don't know why it was not working.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I explained why in the first line. You had `AS t1` and `AS t2` in the `UNION` query, it's not allowed there.